# Rails 5 tags array turning into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, tags, ruby-on-rails-5

BLUF: My tags array for posts works fine to create and read the tags, but when I edit the post, the form field strips the tags array of their commas; the users has to manually re-enter the commas into the tags field, even if they aren't updating it, or else the tags get joined to together in one long string.

Details: using rails 5 and the acts_as_taggable_on gem.

My Post model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord

  acts_as_taggable
```

in my Controller:

```
   private

   def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:post_type, :title, :content, :picture, :body_parts,
                                  :duration, :equipment, :calories, :protein,
                                  :fat, :carbs, :ingredients, tag_list:[] )
   end
```

in my form view:

```
 <%= form_for(@post, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span>
          <%= f.text_field :tag_list, multiple: true, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <%= link_to "Cancel", post_path(@post), class: "btn btn-default" %>

      <% end %>
```

in the post show view:

```
  <%= raw post.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
```

I don't' know what else is relevant, but like I said, everything works fine until i try and edit the post, and then the text_field strips out the commas

Thanks in advance for any advice,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add tags to `text_field` through `value` argument and convert them to comma delimiter string.

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list, value: f.object.tag_list.to_s, multiple: true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Comment: First post, best post!